# Dynamic stops when shorten section

Tags: dynamic

When I shorten the sections so I can get the input (slider bar) and out put on the page, `Dynamic` no longer works. `Dynamic` only works if you keep all the sections open. Is this a bug or is this supposed to happen?

Comment: It's supposed to, Dynamic is only taken care of if it is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this info is somewhere on top of tutorials or a Dynamic documentation, it isn't so let me add this answer:

[**tutorial / AdvancedDynamicFunctionality / Automatic Updates of Dynamic Objects**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996)

> [...]
>
> **`Dynamic` outputs are only updated when they are visible on screen.**
>
> [...]
>
> Outputs that are scrolled off-screen, above or below the current document position, will be left unexamined until the next time they are scrolled on-screen, at which point they are updated before being displayed.
>
> (Thus the fact that they stopped updating is not normally apparent, unless they have side effects, which is discouraged in general.)

The last sentence means that it is discouraged to do something like

```
Dynamic[calculations and result]
```

You should design your GUI such way that you only have `Dynamic[result]` while calculations are triggered by something stable, like events in `EventHandler`, `Buttons` or other controllers. Or even `NotebookDynamicExpressions`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shorten the `input` only by double-clicking on the `output`, NOT `input`, "cell designator" or whatever those lines on the right are called. Make sure you double-click on the leftmost one, i.e. the `output` cell designator. I think, this way, your `Dynamic` stays active.

Comment: I see, let me see if I can figure out how to keep it activated. I think they might have an option for it.